# "Also" and "as well" in the same sentence

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, redundancy

> Make sure that the keyboard shortcuts are accessible using US keyboard layout (since it guarantees that they will be **also** accessible using almost any other keyboard layout—e.g., German one—**as well**).

Is it correct to use "also" and "as well" in such a way? Is it better to remove one of them?

Comment: Yes; this, unlike some, is a meritless tautology. Your outer parenthetical equates to (since it guarantees that they will be accessible using almost any other keyboard layout [for example, a German one] as well also).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Edwin, thanks :-)